# query postgresql jsonb dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsonb

I'm trying to return json data based on dates. Start and end date. Data saved in JSONB column.

```
a.net_revenue = [{"date"=>"2015-01-30", "net_revenue"=>4300}, {"date"=>"2015-01-31", "net_revenue"=>12300}]
```

I'm trying to filter `a.net_revenue` array where date in between `start_date` and `end_date` params

```
Something like a.net_revenue.where('date ->> ?', '2015-01-01')
```

It currently outputs `undefined method 'where' for Array`. Not sure how to filter array with ruby and JSON dates.

Answer (score 0):

As you have an array of jsons you could do something like this:

```
a.net_revenue.select{ |n| n["date"].to_date > start_date && n["date"].to_date < end_date }
```